# state and props are undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux

Hi Im fairly new to coding. I am using react redux and created a store, reducers etc. I cant get anything to render to the screen and when I console.log this.props it comes up an empty array. The data Im dealing with is an array of objects I set the initialstate to an array of objects. I connected all the components with connect and mapstateto props function, there is an empty object in the first arguement of the connect and the second arguement is the componenet. When I look at my component tree it looks fine but my state is undefined and cant figure out why? Here is my code. Thank you in advance.

```
  export const FETCH_SMURFS_START ="FETCH__SMURFS_START"
export const FETCH_SMURFS_SUCCESS = "FETCH_SMURFS_SUCCESS"
export const FETCH_SMURFS_FAILURE ="FETCH_SMURFS_FAILURE"
export const ADD_SMURF_START = "ADD_SMURF_START"
export const ADD_SMURF_SUCCESS = "ADD_SMURF_SUCCESS"
export const ADD_SMURF_FAILURE = "ADD_SMURF_FAILURE"

export const getSmurfData = () =>dispatch=>{
         
    dispatch({type:FETCH_SMURFS_START})
        console.log(FETCH_SMURFS_START)
   axios.get(' http://localhost:3333/smurfs')
      .then((res)=>{
         console.log(res.data)
          dispatch({type:FETCH_SMURFS_SUCCESS, payload:res.datay})

      })
          
      .catch((err)=> {
          dispatch({type:FETCH_SMURFS_FAILURE, payload:err.message})
      })

}

export const putSmurfData = () =>dispatch=>{

    dispatch({type:ADD_SMURF_START})
        console.log(ADD_SMURF_START)
        dispatch({ADD_SMURF_SUCCESS})
   axios.put(' http://localhost:3333/smurfs')
      .then((res)=>{
          
          dispatch({type:ADD_SMURF_SUCCESS, payload:res.data})

      })
          
      .catch((err)=> {
          dispatch({type:ADD_SMURF_FAILURE, payload:err.message})
      })

}

class SmurfDisplay extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    getSmurfData();
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <>
      <div>
        {this.props.newSmurfData.map((smurf, index) => (
          <div>
            <h4 key={smurf.id}></h4>
            <p> {index}</p>
            <p>{smurf.description}</p>
            <p>{smurf.nickname}</p>
            <p>{smurf.name}</p>
            <p>{smurf.position}</p>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
      
      </>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    newSmurfData: [
      {
        error:state.error,
        id: state.id,
        name: state.name,
        position: state.position,
        nickname: state.nickname,
        description: state.description,
      },
    ],
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {})(SmurfDisplay);
class Smurf extends React.Component {
    render() {
        console.log(this.props);
        return (
            <>
            
                  {this.props.smurfData.map(function(smurf,index) {
                      return(
                      
                <div>
                      <h4 key={index}></h4>
                      <p>{smurf.description}</p>
                      <p>{smurf.nickname}</p>               
                      <p>{smurf.name}</p>
                      <p>{smurf.position}</p>
                   
              </div>
                      )  
                  })}

                  
            
    </>
            
                  
        )
    }
}










const mapStateToProps = (state) =>{
    return{

        smurfData:[{
            error:state.error,
            id:state.id,
            name:state.name,
            position:state.position,
            nickname:state.nickname,
            description:state.description
        }]
    

    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps,{})(Smurf)
xport const initialState = {
        error:"",
        isLoading: false,
        smurfData : [{
            id:"",
            name:"",
            position:"",
            nickname:"",
            description:""

        }],

        error:"",
        isAddingSmurf:false,
        newSmurfData:[{
            id:"",
            name:"",
            position:"",
            nickname:"",
            description:""
        }],
     
        
        }
        




export const reducer = (state = initialState,action) =>{
                switch(action.type){
         case FETCH_SMURFS_START:
                  return{
                    ...state,
                    isLoading:true,
                    error:""
                }
        case FETCH_SMURFS_SUCCESS:
                return{
                    ...state,
                    isLoading:false,
                    smurfData:action.payload
                }
        case FETCH_SMURFS_FAILURE:
            return{
                ...state,
                isLoading:false,
                error:"there was an error getting your smurfs"
            }
                
        case ADD_SMURF_START:
            return{
                ...state,
                isAddingSmurf:false,
                error:""
            }
        case ADD_SMURF_SUCCESS:
            return{
                ...state,
                isAddingSmurf:true,
                error: "",
                newSmurfData:action.payload
            }
        case ADD_SMURF_FAILURE:
            return{
                ...state,
                isAddingSmurf:false,
                addingError:"Error"
            }
                    default:
                    return state



    }
}

export default reducer;
```

Comment: Your actions are setup to be used in [`mapDispatchToProps`](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch) but you are not using the second param of `connect`.

Comment: Since you're new to coding and React I would recommend that you stop using class based components immediately and instead switch to functional components. There aren't  any advantages to using class based components and switching to functional components eliminates a lot of possible errors. Functional components are the newer solution that solves various problems with class based components. In fact the error you're experiencing would not even be possible in a functional component.

Answer (score -1):

when you want to use `this.props` in your `class Component` you need to use `super(props)` inside the constructor:

```
constructor(props){
   super(props)
}
```

Comment: actually this is not necessary for some years. you don't need to call constructor at all, it's called implicity. also you can define your state outside, which would make your code cleaner.

Comment: @buzatto intresting, thanks I didn't know that